# AngularJS: How to validate ng-repeat form fields

Tags: angularjs

The code below is my attempt to validate a list of values in a form. The values are in a table within an `ng-repeat` directive and should be validated as required. Any inputs will be appreciated.

```
<form name="form1">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="param in params">
     <td>
        {{param.name}}
     </td>
     <td>
         <input name="i{{$index}}" ng-model="param.val" required />
         <span style="color:red" ng-show="form1.i{{$index}}.$dirty && form1.i{{$index}}.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="form1.i{{$index}}.required">This field is required</span>
         </span>
       </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think @SunilD'2 comment to another answer is worth an answer of its own, because the approach with `ng-form` can facilitate more validation scenarios (for example, highlighting a row in the table where one of the inputs is invalid)

```
<form name="form1">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="param in params">
     <td>
        {{param.name}}
     </td>
     <td ng-form="cellForm">
         <input ng-model="param.val" required />
         <span ng-show="cellForm.$dirty && cellForm.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="cellForm.$error.required">This field is required</span>
         </span>
       </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Validity of nested `ng-form` sets the validity of their parent form.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XWeMFf3RH2y3OcFqRBEO?p=preview)

Comment: I tried the plunker but cannot submit the form, the submit button is missing

Comment: I don't understand the issue. You don't have a submit button in your original question.

Comment: That's fine, but it gives me no additional information to understand what your issue is about. Either edit the question, or - better - ask a new question

Answer (score 3):

```
<form name="form1" ng-controller="mycontroller">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="param in params">
        <td>{{param.name}}</td>
        <td>
          <input name="i{{$index}}" ng-model="param.val" required="" />
          <span style="color:red" ng-show="form1.['i{{$index}}'].$dirty && form1.['i{{$index}}'].$invalid">
            <span ng-show="form1.['i{{$index}}'].required">This field is required</span>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Working sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/pxtnW5vzWP8J4KYno3jN?p=preview

Comment: A slightly cleaner solution might use the `ng-form` directive (on the 2nd `<td>` element, or on the `<tr>` element) to create nested forms under the `<form>` tag. You then give a simple name for the `<input>` tag (like "myInput"). That would allow you get rid of funky expressions like `form1.['i{{$index}}']` and replace them with `form1.nestedForm.myInput`.

Comment: This code generates a bunch of errors in the console

Comment: Is it possible to use the $index in the controller and then show the error message? I am trying to show the error on form submission.